# Unable to set the data property xxx as the parent data structure is not set

Tags: location

I currently use geofield to set latitude and longitude but rules gives me this error:

> 0 ms Unable to modify data "user:field-coordonnees:lon": Unable to set the data property lon as the parent data structure is not set.

So values are not set and I do not understand why, it's just a set data.
The value exists because I can see it in a "Show a message on the site". I've also tried to cast the value as Integer, nothing has changed.

Any idea ?

Configuration:

> Geofield Map 7.x-2.3
>
> Geofield 7.x-2.3
>
> geoPHP 7.x-1.7

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue.
In fact insted of set a lat and a lon value, I had to use "Create geofield values from lat/lon".

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error it's most likely that the developer forgot to add a proper check (or try/catch block) for his entity_metadata_wrapper() call. Better report this to the module you were using on the drupal.org/geofield page.